# Building SOAP Envelope from Java using Strings

Tags: java, wcf, soap

I am working on understanding how SOAP services work.My client is in Java and the service is using WCF (although in theory this shouldn't matter). If I am given an example of a SOAP envelope and do the following:

```
-Build a SOAP envelope that exactly follows the example
-Use an HttpPost object to post the data to www.service.com/service.svc
```

Is this a correct (although improper) way to call the service? Because when I do this, I receive a 400 response, even though my SOAP envelope is the exact same as the example.

Comment: What binding is the WCF service, and which version of SOAP are you using?  WCF uses `basicHttpBinding` for SOAP 1.1 - all others (I believe) are 1.2.

Comment: We are using SOAP 1.2, but I am unsure of the binding we are using. It seems pretty reasonable that BasicHttpBinding is what I want for this scenario

Comment: After a quick check, the config file does indeed specify that we use basicHttpBinding `<protocolMapping><add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" /></protocolMapping> `

Or is this not the proper way to specify the binding?

Comment: Is this the config file for the client or the service?  By the way, `basicHttp**s**binding` is not the same as `basicHttpBinding` - the first is designed for TLS.  Also, the segment above is simply the default bindings.  Are you able to post the whole config file?

Comment: This is the binding for the service. I am just writing a non-WCF client side application to consume the service.

The full config file is available here: https://gist.github.com/andrewnguyen42/5477069

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You are probably missing some required headers. I suggest to use a TCP monitor, intercept a working request and analize its content.

Comment: Is it an HTTP header? Or a SOAP header? In the Post, I only specify the Content-type as "text/xml". I am relatively new to consuming web-services so I guess I don't know what else I could need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are getting an HTTP 400 (Bad Request) is that your service is using `BasicHttpBinding` which is SOAP 1.1, and you are most likely sending a SOAP 1.2 message (as you indicated in the comments that you are using SOAP 1.2). The message formats are different between the two.

The simplest solution would be to use SOAP 1.1, but if you must (or want) to use SOAP 1.2, the following may help.

In your config file, you haven't defined any endpoints or bindings - which is ok, as WCF will use defaults in 4.0 and later.

However, the default binding for HTTP is `BasicHttpBinding`.  You need to use a binding that supports SOAP 1.2 (or change your message to SOAP 1.1).  You could use `WSHttpBinding`, which does support SOAP 1.2, but you mau have to change the security setting (by default it's Windows).

Another option is to use a custom binding that implements SOAP1.1.

I'll give a couple of examples (I've never written a non-.NET client for a WCF service, so I can't say for certain that it will work but it should at least get you going in the right direction.

**WSHttpBinding**

Change the default protocol mapping for HTTP requests from `BasicHttpBinding` to `WsHttpBinding` by overriding the protocol mapping in your config file:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <addBinding protocol="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Add a binding section to your config file so you can set the security mode to None.  This goes under the `<system.serviceModel>` section:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding>
        <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Notice that I didn't set a value for the `name` attribute on the binding.  This will set the binding definition as the default, and in conjunction with changing the default protocol for HTTP to `wsHttpBinding` should enable you to send SOAP 1.2.

**SECURITY NOTE*** Setting security to none is fine if you're just trying to get a better understanding of SOAP, but I would highly recommend doing it in production.

**Custom Binding**

I've never used a custom binding, but something like this should work:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="Custom">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <httTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

You will need to explicitly set this to your endpoint (using the `bindingConfiguration` attribute of the endpoint), which means you'll need to create an endpoint definition in your config file.

The custom binding idea is from [SOAP 1.2 message format with BasicHttpBinding](http://www.pvle.be/2008/10/soap-12-message-format-with-basichttpbinding/)

Hopefully this will give you some ideas and get you going again.